# symfony2 how to create query builder between two dates with startdate enddate included

Tags: query-builder, symfony-2.8

How to create query builder between two dates (startdate enddate) with startDate endDate included.
SQL example :  `Select * from fiche.f
WHERER ((f.creationdate >= satrtDate) 
AND (f.creationdate <= endDate))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$startdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start. ' - 1 days'))` and `$enddate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($end. ' + 1 days'))`

Comment: $startdate = $startdate->format('Y-m-d') . ' 00:00:00';

$enddate = $enddate->format('Y-m-d') . ' 23:59:59';

Answer (score 2):

In PostgreSQL, I would use `BETWEEN $date1 and $date2` and it seems to work in Doctrine too.

```
$queryBuilder->where('f.creationdate BETWEEN f.startDate and f.endDate')
```

Comment: I use `where('f.ficheCreated BETWEEN :beginDate AND :endDate')` but when I choose startDate = EndDate no data find